# EMMIP/LSMMIP plot from glmer model

Tags: lme4-nlme

I need to create a plot from a `glmer` model, and I tried to use EMMIP function for this:

```
model<-glmer(Accuracy ~ day, dataframe, family = 'binomial')
emmip(model, ~ day, xlab = "day", ylab = "Accuracy", main = "XXX")
```

Although it produces a seemingly accurate plot, it has a strange y-axis labelling. It is strange because I want it to be mean percentage of accuracy, but it shows definitely something else. It is interesting that when I use `emmip()` with an ANOVA model I don't have this problem. Does anybody know if there is anything I could do to have accurate information on y-axis?

Comment: can you tell us what kind of plot this is supposed to be, and what package the `emmip()` function comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need `type="response"`; the default is to make predictions on the *linear predictor* scale, which for a binomial model is the logit or log-odds scale.

From `?emmeans:emmip`:

> type: As in ‘predict.emmGrid’, this determines whether we want to
>             inverse-transform the predictions (‘type = "response"’) or
>             not (any other choice). The default is ‘"link"’, unless the
>             ‘"predict.type"’ option is in force; see ‘emm_options’.

By the way, if we're being picky, this will be a *proportion* response (0-1), not a percentage (0-100); I don't know offhand if there's a way to multiply the prediction by 100.

Comment: Ben Bolker, thank you very much - the problem is solved!!